# render react component when prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-router-dom, react-props

how to force render our component when props changes? 
how to force render parent component when child component's props changes?

i searched a lot but all solutions are deprecated in new React version.

in my any pages (Route exact path="/post/:id" component={post}) for example (siteUrl/post/1) i am getting (:id) from props (this.props.match.params) and that works.

but when i am in single page component (Post) and this Route (siteUrl/post/1) when i am passing new Props to this component (:id).

props will changes but single component and parent component Will not re render...

Comment: normally when you want the parent to re-render on child changes you call some function on parent and then change a parent state which will make it re-render

Comment: You should make use of `componentWillReceiveProps` or in newer versions use `getDerivedStateFromProps` and set your state appropriately that would trigger the re-render

Comment: hear, i need child component re-render it's parent component... i searched a lot but all solutions was deprecated

Comment: alternatively, you can use `{ this.state.visible && (... you component to force rerender...) }` to render and then switch state `visible` value orderly to `false` and then to `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be using componentDidMount method.

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

but you need to use  componentDidUpdate.

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs.
>   This method is not called for the initial render.

You can also use state and other React features without writing a class.
read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 2):

To make both parent and child re-render you need to path prop from parent to it's child.

```
   // parent using
   <Parent someProp={{someVal}} />

   // parent render:

   render() {
      const { someProp } = this.props
      <Child someProp={{someProp}} />
   }
```

this will surely re-render both components, unless you stated another logic in `componentShouldUpdate`

in your case `Router` looks like a parent for `Parent` so you should only path `:id` as a prop.

Make sure `Router` is at the top level, right under the `App`

Answer (score 0):

Important is ,that you initialise the someVal of the child first in the constructor

```
 public static getDerivedStateFromProps(
        nextProps,
        nextState
      ) {
        let { someVal } = nextProps;
        if (nextState.someVal !== someVal) {
          return {
            initialVal,
            someVal: someVal
          };
        }
        return null;
      }
```

After it will rerender on prop changes because the state changes